# CakePHP Plugin routes no longer working after upgrading from 2.4.5 to 2.6.7

Tags: url, cakephp, plugins, path, routes

The URL paths to Plugin controller actions are no longer working after upgrading the Cake core to 2.6.7.

For example, visiting a URL like: mysite.com/plugin_name/controller_name/action

gives me a 'controller' not found error. These paths were working prior to the update, which leads me to believe that something changed in the API between the versions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be that I had some Configure::load() calls before the CakePlugin::load() calls in my bootstrap.php file.

Moving the Configure::load() calls after all of the plugin loads fixed the issue for me.

As for why this was happening:
It looks like in version 2.6 of CakePHP, calling Configure::load() will cause /lib/Cake/Config/routes.php to be loaded. This file loads all of the URL parsing patterns for the Router class. If no plugins have been loaded at the time this file has been included, then the URL parsing patterns for plugins (like '/:plugin/:controller/:action/*') will not be loaded.